# Javascript to populate phone number into 3 input textboxes with indentical names no id

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, asp-classic

I essentially have some weird voodoo stuff I have to fix.

This old classic asp code for generating textboxes looks like this

```
<%i3_addPhoneFields "requestorPhone1","Phone <font class =txtMedium>:<font color = red>*</font></font>",i3_EmpPhoneNumber%>
```

I see that the OUTPUT view source is

```
<input class="txtSmall" type="text" name="requestorPhone1" value="" size="3" maxlength="3">
<input class="txtSmall" type="text" name="requestorPhone1" value="" size="3" maxlength="3">
<input class="txtSmall" type="text" name="requestorPhone1" value="" size="4" maxlength="4">
```

1. I didn't know the name repeated 3 times is valid html
2. I cannot just add in ID's for each one
3. I cannot just go changing all this code for several reasons.

I have javascript variables for phone number like this:

```
 (888) 433-3017
```

What I have is essentially added in Jquery

If I do this then ALL 3 text boxes will essentially get the same value (222 - obviously)

```
$('input[name="requestorPhone1"]').val('222');
```

**GOAL**

To use javascript / jquery with regex and to take

```
(888) 433-3017
```

**For 1st textbox to put in 888 ,  2nd textbox  433 ,  3rd textbox  3017**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach for splitting the number and then populating it into textboxes:

```
function doIt() {
    var myString = "(123) 456-7890"; //hard-coded number for demo
    myString = myString.replace(/\D/g,''); //remove all non-numerics
    console.log(myString);

    //extract component parts from the full number string
    var first = myString.substr(0,3); //extract the first part of number
    var second = myString.substr(3,3); //second part
    var third = myString.substr(6,4); //third part
    console.log(first, second, third);

    //use jQuery's eq() to select specific elements in order
    $('input[name="requestorPhone1"]:eq(0)').val(first);
    $('input[name="requestorPhone1"]:eq(1)').val(second);
    $('input[name="requestorPhone1"]:eq(2)').val(third);
}
```

There's  JSFiddle demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/hh2o1bek/

Obviously I've hard-coded the number, but this should be enough to point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

You could something like this:

```
var els = document.getElementsByClassName("txtSmall");
if (els[0]) 
  els[0].value = "888";
if (els[1])
  els[1].value = "433";
if (els[2])
  els[2].value = "3017";
```

Answer (score 0):

JS + Jquery :

```
str = '(888) 433-3017';
a = str.split(' ');
a[0] = a[0].replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
b = a[1].split('-');

$('input[name="requestorPhone1"]').eq(0).val(a[0]);
$('input[name="requestorPhone1"]').eq(1).val(b[0]);
$('input[name="requestorPhone1"]').eq(2).val(b[1]);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/y9w8nwop/2/